# Is it possible to group AssetTrans by financial dimensions

Tags: axapta, dimensions, x++, microsoft-dynamics, ax

Hi I need to remake AssetSumCalc calss to make possible to group amounts by Financial dimensions. What I actually need is to pass one parameter value, like "Cost center", and group whole assetTrans by that dimension. Is it possible to do it by Query? I only found `SysQuery::addOrderByDimensionAttribute()`

method which allows ordering by fin. dimensions, but there's no grouping.

Do I think correctly, that there is only one way doing it with Temp table, because there is no way to group ax2012 financial dimensions straight with Query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct, out of the box.

The implementation of the method is in class `DimensionProvider` method `addOrderByAttribute`.
It should take seconds to copy that method, then do a global replace of 'OrderBy' with 'GroupBy'. Then do the same thing in class `SysQuery` and interface `DimensionProviderBase`.

Your testing will show whether is works or not.